# What is advantage/consideration to have nameless array

Tags: c

I ran across such C code:

```
static char *mem_types[M_CNT] = {
    [M_ABC] = "abc",
    [M_DEF] = "DEF",
    [M_XYZ] = "XYZ",
};
```

M_CNT is a macro constant; M_ABC, M_DEF and M_XYZ are all enum.

Such declarations look strange to me, or rather, I am wondering what is the advantage to declare a string array like this. I would simply put it as

```
static char *mem_types[M_CNT] = {
    "abc",
    "DEF",
    "XYZ",
};
```

The only thing I can think of is, the declaration can exactly limit the size of each string.

Is there any other consideration?

Comment: "the declaration can exactly limit the size of each string" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: @my_question: Those bracketed things are not the length of each string, rather they're indices into the main array.  And they can't be used in C++.

Comment: Removed C++ tag, as this is C99 but not valid C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes your code immune to re-ordering of the enum values. Here is an illustration of how it works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum {
   aa, bb, cc
};

static char *mem_types[3] = {
    [aa] = "abc",
    [cc] = "DEF",
    [bb] = "XYZ",
};

int main() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0 ; i != 3 ; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", mem_types[i]);
    }
}
```

This is what the program printed. Note how `XYZ` and `DEF` have switched places to match the order of the `enum`.

```
abc
XYZ
DEF
```

Answer (score 1):

If new lines may be inserted in the array from time to time, the `[M_ABC]` version is guaranteed to keep the enum values in line with where the corresponding data lives in the array. Additionally, it provides a signal to any developers reading this code that the enum is definitely still in sync with the actual array definition.

This would be preferable to having code reference, say, `mem_types[1]` somewhere and having to figure out if it's trying to refer to the old meaning or the new meaning of the magic constant 1.